# Calculate mass from time dilation

Tags: gravity, mass, time, time-dilation

Hi not a physicist in any way so was wondering if I know the age (time passed) and mass of an one object and the age (time passed) of another object, can I calculate its mass?

So Object 1 is Earth:
Time passed: 4.543 billion earth years (age)
Mass: 5.972 × 10^24 kg

Object 2:
Time passed: 6 earth days
What would be the mass of object 2?

thanks!

Comment: Time passed since when? And in what reference frame? Time is relative, not absolute.

Comment: Lets say at time 0 on Earth, time was also 0 in Object 2 and the 2 times I mention are relative change between Earth and Object 2 is  due to object 2 being much bigger

Comment: Sorry not sure if i made sense in the comment, let me put it another way, You stand on earth and i stand on Object 2 at the same start time. For you 4.543 billion years have passed but for me its only been 6 days. Can I calculate the mass of the object I am standing on?

Comment: Would also require the radius of the object (we know the radius of the Earth). We might make do with assuming that both are modelled by Schwarzchild black hole, but we must have the radius to begin this calculation.

Comment: Can we assume that the mass to radius ratio of object 2 is the same as Earth